# For the life of me I can't get my nougat to set hard

Tags: food-science, sugar, dessert, candy, melting-sugar

Recipe:

**Syrup**

- 1 cup sugar
- 1/2 cup corn syrup
- 1/8 cup water (I dont think this does anything)
- Dash of salt

**Egg white**

- 1 egg white whipped
- Dash of cream of tartar to stabilize the egg white
- 2 tbsp rose water after eggs are whipped before syrup is added
- As many nuts as I want

I get the syrup up to 300F. I whip the eggs, then before I temper them with a little syrup at around 220-250F, I add the rose water. Then I slowly add the syrup to the eggs while mixing and beat the mixture until it hits the right consistency and add nuts. It *seems* like it's thick and it should set right, but it just ends up being softish.

What could be going wrong? I've checked my thermometer and it's correct. Do I add more sugar or decrease the egg whites (or both)? Is it something I'm doing wrong with the eggs? I beat them until they have a peak when I remove the mixing things. Am I beating it too early and it falls apart (is that even a thing)? Should I not add the rose water after I beat the eggs? What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, the water in the syrup is there to help the sugar dissolve, which avoids the syrup crystallizing. By the time you hit 300F, most of it will have evaporated.